# Complex numbers lies on ellipse

Tags: complex-numbers

$ z $ is a variable complex number such that $ |z|=2$. Show that the point $ z+ \frac{1}{z} $ lies on an ellipse of eccentricity $\frac{4}{5}$ in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|=2$ then we can write $z=2e^{i\theta}$

Then $w=z+\frac 1z=2e^{i\theta}+\frac 12 e^{-i\theta}=\frac 52 \cos\theta+\frac 32 i\sin\theta$

It should be pretty obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

As you know $|z|=2$, you can write $z$ as a function of its argument $$z = 2\cos\varphi + 2i\sin\varphi $$
and then $$\begin{align}\frac 1z & = \frac 12\cos(-\varphi) + \frac i2\sin(-\varphi) \\ & = \frac 12\cos\varphi - \frac i2\sin\varphi\end{align}$$
so $$\begin{align}z+\frac 1z & = \left(2+\frac 12\right)\cos\varphi + i\left(2-\frac 12\right)\sin\varphi \\ & = \frac 52\cos\varphi + i\frac 32\sin\varphi \end{align}$$

Now you need only to show that the locus of $(x,y)=(\frac 52\cos\varphi, \frac 32\sin\varphi)$ is an ellipse of a given eccentricity.